# NTLM authentication HttpClient in Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, httpclient, ntlm

I am trying to use the HttpClient to access a REST service which requires NTLM authentication. However I keep getting a 401 Unauthorized.
My code looks like this

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:15001");
        var credentialsCache = new CredentialCache { { uri, "NTLM", CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials } };
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentialsCache };
        var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = uri, Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10) };
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        var response = httpClient.GetAsync("api/MyMethod").Result;
    }
```

My target framework is netcoreapp2.0. If I change to net461, it will work. Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check out this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/9234

Comment: Thanks so much for your question - it helped us to implement NTLM request on .Net

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Microsoft has accepted this as a bug. Possibly a fix will be released with core 2.1

https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25988

Answer (score 0):

Default NTLM authentication and Kerberos authentication use the Microsoft Windows user credentials associated with the calling application to attempt authentication with the server. When using non-default NTLM authentication, the application sets the authentication type to NTLM and uses a NetworkCredential object to pass the user name, password, and domain to the host, as shown in the following example.

```
string myUri = "http://www.contoso.com/";
using HttpClientHandler handler = new()
{
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(UserName, SecurelyStoredPassword, Domain),
};
using HttpClient client = new(handler);
string result = await client.GetStringAsync(myUri);
// Do Other Stuff...
```

Applications that need to connect to Internet services using the credentials of the application user can do so with the user's default credentials, as shown in the following example.

```
string myUri = "http://www.contoso.com/";
using HttpClientHandler handler = new()
{
    Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials,
};
using HttpClient client = new(handler);
string result = await client.GetStringAsync(myUri);
// Do Other Stuff...
```

The negotiate authentication module determines whether the remote server is using NTLM or Kerberos authentication, and sends the appropriate response.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/ntlm-and-kerberos-authentication

**In other words, NTLM authentication is implicit.**