# Exchange Web Services 401 error on Debian but not windows

Tags: c#, .net, linux, asp.net-core, exchangewebservices

The following code works fine on windows but on debian is returning a 401 - anonymous request disallowed. It is using DotNet core 2.0.0. If that helps. I think it may be because the machine on windows is somehow discovering the domain while the debian machine is not. I'm not sure. Any help is appreciated.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
            service.EnableScpLookup = false;
            service.TraceEnabled = true;
            service.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            service.PreAuthenticate = false;
            service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.All;
            try
            {
                service.Url = new Uri("https:/domain/ews/Exchange.asmx");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("webService Uri:" + ex));
            }
            try
            {
                service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("username", "pass","domain");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new Exception(string.Format("Credentials:" + ex));
            }
            try
            {
                EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
                email.ToRecipients.Add("user@domain.com");
                email.Subject = "HelloWorld";
                email.Body = new MessageBody("This is the first email I've sent by using the EWS Managed API");
                email.Save();
                email.Send();
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit 1:** If it helps I can put the trace of the soap and the exception with email ommited:

```
<trace Tag="EwsRequestHttpHeaders" Tid="1" Time="2018-07-20 09:31:08Z">
POST /ews/Exchange.asmx HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Accept: text/xml
User-Agent: ExchangeServicesClient/15.00.0913.015
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate


</Trace>
<Trace Tag="EwsRequest" Tid="1" Time="2018-07-20 09:31:09Z" 
Version="15.00.0913.015">
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Header>
     <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013_SP1" />
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
     <m:CreateItem MessageDisposition="SaveOnly">
       <m:Items>
         <t:Message>
           <t:Subject>HelloWorld</t:Subject>
           <t:Body BodyType="HTML">This is the first email I've sent by using the EWS Managed API</t:Body>
           <t:ToRecipients>
             <t:Mailbox>
               <t:EmailAddress>**********@******.com</t:EmailAddress>
             </t:Mailbox>
           </t:ToRecipients>
         </t:Message>
       </m:Items>
     </m:CreateItem>
   </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
</Trace>
<Trace Tag="EwsResponseHttpHeaders" Tid="1" Time="2018-07-20 09:31:12Z">
HTTP/1.1 401 Anonymous Request Disallowed
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
request-id: 13c632cd-7642-4e26-ad5d-48dce4b52d35
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate, NTLM
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-FEServer: FTLPEX02CAS02
Date: Fri, 20 Jul 2018 09:31:11 GMT
Content-Length: 0


</Trace>
```

Comment: Does this answer help: [SOAP authentication fails when running a c# app on a linux box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49121998/33499)?

Comment: Not really, I tried to cache my credentials and then specify NTML as the auth type then send it on, this works fine on Windows (as does my original code), but has the same error on Debian. It is possible I misunderstood though.

Comment: I tried changing the DotNet core version to 2.1 as well but that gave me some weird kerberos error

Answer (score 0):

This answer is 3 years too late to help the OP, but it may help some other poor head-scratching soul. I was experiencing the same symptoms, but on macOS, with .Net Core 3.1, and the fix I found was to use only the schema + hostname in the service URL. No path elements.

Instead of

> `service.Url = new Uri("https:/domain/ews/Exchange.asmx");`

use

> `service.Url = new Uri("https:/domain");`

I stumbled upon this solution, which I'm sure is glaringly obvious to more experienced .Net devs, after trying all sorts of other potential solutions. I tried including the AD domain in the username (DOMAIN\username), using `CredentialCache` with an entry for `NTLM`, toggling `PreAuthenticate`, including various domain names in `NetworkCredential`, `Basic` authorization, and more. All failed with the dreaded `401` until I chopped the path off of the service URL.