# Windows authentication in Linux Docker container .Net 5

Tags: docker, kubernetes, .net-core, kerberos, windows-authentication

**Summary**

I'm trying to configure **Windows Authentication** using **Linux Docker Container** and **Kerberos**.

The project is written in *ASP.NET Core 5.0 Web API* on the `aspnet:5.0-buster-slim` image.

During development, I have followed [this official article from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#kestrel)  and also [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60296237/windows-authentication-in-linux-docker-container).

I've managed to solve many problems along the way and have fully configured Kerberos in the container. The problem might be related to the way I created the `spn`s.

**Background**

- Nodes: CentOS
- Orchestrator: Kubernetes
- Base Image: `aspnet:5.0-buster-slim`
- Additional Dependencies: `syslog-ng realmd gss-ntlmssp krb5-kdc-ldap krb5-admin-server ldap-utils curl default-jre krb5-user krb5-kdc krb5-config`
- Volumes: Valid `krb5.conf` mounted at `/etc/krb5.conf`
- Domain: MyDomain.com *(This is just an example)*
- Ingress: SSL termination for the wildcard `CNAME` is `*.it.MyDomain.com` using `cert-manager`
- AD Principal: `app_usr`
- SPN: `http/template@MYDOMAIN.COM`, `http/template.it.MyDomain.com`

**Setup**

I performed the test on an app named *Template* so the fqdn name of it is `Template.it.MyDomain.com`

After doing so, I successfully created a `keytab` file and also double-checked my self by looking at the user principle name and its sets to `http/template@MYDOMAIN.COM`

After deploying the app I opened the execution shell and successfully performed `kinit` to `app_usr` with the keytab file.
Performing `klist` shows a valid ticket.

So the infrastructure seems to be configured correctly, moving to the application level.
In the `startup.cs` file at the `ConfigureService` I have added authentication:
First attempt I tried the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
```

The next attempt was as follows:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate(options =>
    {
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
        {
            options.EnableLdap("MyDomain.com");
        }
    });
```

and even like so:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddNegotiate(options =>
    {
        if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
        {
            options.EnableLdap(settings =>
            {
                settings.Domain = "MyDomain.com";
                settings.MachineAccountName = "app_usr";
                settings.MachineAccountPassword = Configuration["Password"]
            });
        }
    });
```

The error is the always:

> GssApiException: GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure. Minor code may provide more information

If I try to access the app with node port I get prompted for user name and password and after that, I get the same gssapi error

Comment: Hi, were you able to find solution for this usecase? I'm in similar situation with React frontend and Django backend though, trying to deploy in Windows corporate network.

Comment: Unfortunately, no